# Pattern matching and with multiple parameters in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

We face a complicated issue in Apache web server running n Linux where intermittently Apache gives 5XX error for some of the URLs and and that too not continuously. Its like starts with few requests and grows in timely manner. The issue resolves once we restart the Apache.

We are trying to fix the issue but we need a work around till the time where we need to put a script to monitor the access log of Apache server and whenever the issue occurs we have to restart the Apache.

We thought a shell script like tailing the log and grep all 5xx errors to a separate file and another shell script which will be triggered by cron will check the file if the error is repeated for number of times within a mentioned time.

My problem is the uRLs are not always same and so I have to grep the file which has the all 5XX errors and need to see if URLs are repeated and time also.

Can anyone suggest me some logic how i can filter the errors like. I tried to be clear but not sure if this is correct way of explaining the issue.

The logs are bit modified with values but format is same.

```
x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y - - [11/May/2016:08:29:05 +0800](0) "HTTPS" "GET /html/js/barebone.jsp?browserId=other&themeId=expressportal_WAR_expressportaltheme&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&minifierBundleId=javascript.barebone.files&languageId=en_US&b=6200&t=1462268846000 HTTP/1.1" 502 319 "https://myportal.test.com/web/guest/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"


x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y - - [11/May/2016:08:29:05 +0800](0) "HTTPS" "GET /combo/?browserId=other&minifierType=&languageId=en_US&b=6200&t=1462268846000&/html/js/aui/event-touch/event-touch-min.js&/html/js/aui/event-move/event-move-min.js HTTP/1.1" 502 319 "https://myportal.test.com/web/guest/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"


x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y - - [11/May/2016:08:29:05 +0800](0) "HTTPS" "GET /html/js/liferay/available_languages.jsp?browserId=other&themeId=expressportal_WAR_expressportaltheme&colorSchemeId=01&minifierType=js&languageId=en_US&b=6200&t=1462268846000 HTTP/1.1" 502 319 "https://myportal.test.com/web/guest/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"


x.x.x.x, y.y.y.y - - [11/May/2016:08:29:05 +0800](0) "HTTPS" "GET /combo/?browserId=other&minifierType=&languageId=en_US&b=6200&t=1462268846000&/html/js/aui/widget-stack/assets/skins/sam/widget-stack.css HTTP/1.1" 502 319 "https://myportal.test.com/web/guest/home" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Can you give some logs for example?

Comment: Hi Avivb, due to word count limitation in comment added the logs above. Thanks for checking my question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you 100% sure a restart fix the 500 errors ? If so, this line in the crontab should do:

```
tail -n 100 /var/log/apache2/error.logs | awk '{if ($9 >= 500) {nb += 1}} END {if (nb > 10) {exit 1}}' /var/log/apache2/access.log || service apache2 restart
```

It means that if there's more than 10 errors in the last 100 lines: restart. You may change the values for your specific problem.

First think I can think is: upgrade your Apache if it's not up to date.

Comment: Hi Julien, Thanks for giving a solution but my problem is different. The 500 error is not bringing down the server, instead its giving 500 for some request and recovering back but once in a week one of the server(3 servers we have) goes down. So we need to check the pattern of the error and then decide if we need a restart.

Comment: Have you diagnosed (by reading logs ? strace ? whatever) if 500 are generated by Apache or a backend ?

Comment: The issue is not clear and that is why we are trying for a work around to restart web server using the script.

Comment: Doesn't your backend log too ? Can you cross-compare logs from apache (exact timestamp where 500 happend) with your backend logs to see if errors were delivered too ?  What does apache error logs tells ?

Comment: The problem is the servers have a very huge traffic and also some of the icons are not loading for some specific mobile phones so those images also thrown as 500 error only, That is why we are trying to identify a pattern which will help us to perform a restart.